# Why completeWithError method doesn't send proper exception message to client in SSE?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, server-sent-events

I am trying to implement Server Sent Event (SSE) with service layer because of complex logic that I have. BE app needs to ping FE for each object that successfully pass the validation check with simple number of object. If all objects pass, than some random response need to be returned. Here is the simplified code that I have in controller:

```
@Lazy
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(ApiEndpoints.BUSINESS_INTELLIGENCE)
@Produces(MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public class PreCheckController {

    @PostMapping("/event")
    public @ResponseBody SseEmitter handle(@Valid @RequestBody PreCheckRequest request) {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        new Thread(() -> {
            preCheckService.checkIfAllObjectsAreValid(request.getIds(), emitter);
        }).start();

        return emitter;
    }
}
```

And this is the code that I have in `PreCheckService`:

```
public void checkIfAllObjectsAreValid(List<Long> ids, SseEmitter emitter) {
    try {
        FinalResponse finalResponse = new FinalResponse();
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
            // Very complex logic here
            if (!isValid()) {
                throw new CustomException(ex);  
            }

            // If this object is valid, send row number from the list to FE, so FE can track the progress
            emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("precheckValidation").data(i + 1));
        }
     // If everything is ok, and all objects are passed, return finalResponse
emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("precheckValidation").data(statePrecheckValidationResponse));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        emitter.completeWithError(e);
    } finally {
        emitter.complete();
    }
}
```

Right now, if everything is ok, postman response looks exactly how I wanted:
[image]

But when I throw new exception the message is not returned to client - sometimes it just send previous message, sometimes doesn't do anything and just close the connection. Any idea what am I missing?